# trying to combine multiple regex patterns

Tags: regex

I am trying to combine 2 regex patterns into a single one and am unable to do so.
The problem that I am trying to solve is to get the string between 2 characters which can occur multiple times within a string.

```
string = /users/test/test1/test2/abcde_482_fhsj_38575.txt
```

I need to get 'abcde' in my result.
When I try to use the following regex, I get all information before the first underscore

```
(.*)^[^_]*_
```

When I try to use the following regex, I get all information after the last '/'

```
.*\/(.*)
```

But I am not able to combine these 2 patterns to get to 'abcde'. I tried using "|" as an operator to combine them as well but it didn't work. Am I doing something incorrect here? Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Try capturing with `^[^_]*\/([^\/_]+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/36DWt5/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
^[^_]*\/([^\/_]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/36DWt5/1), grab the value inside Group 1.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^_]*` - any zero or more chars other than `_`, as many as possible
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([^\/_]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than `/` and `_`.